# Installing Android app on Droid phone

Tags: java, android, deployment, android-sdk-2.3

I recently completed programming an Android application and I would like to try it on my phone. I followed online instructions and put the .apk file on my phone via dropbox. However when I go into dropbox on my phone to install the application my phone says "There is a problem parsing the package." Can someone help me resolve this issue?

I programmed in eclipse using the android emulator and AVD. I have enabled my phone to use unknown sources. It runs fine on the android emulator. I am using Android 4.0.3.

I am using a Droid Pro
Model #: 4.7.3
Android Version: 2.3.4 <- could this be the issue?

Comment: apparently there was a problem. Parsing something. the package to be precise. How is anyone supposed to help you fix this without more information? Did it work on your AVD? For hwat version of android did you program? How did you make the apk? Did it work on another phone? Did you set non-market apps to 'true' ? etc etc

Comment: I am new to this whole experience. I used the eclipse android emulator to program the application. It did work on the AVD. Version 4.0.3 I believe. Yes I did set non-market apps to be true.

Comment: Maybe the file wasn't uploaded properly, or is corrupt? Can you download the file to your PC and confirm that is it a valid apk file. You can do this by opening it in a program like WinZip or WinRar - if it opens without error, it isn't corrupt.

Comment: Please add more information to the question. You might be new to android dev, but not to asking questions at all I hope? Also add how you made the apk, if / how you tested the apk (after creation!) on your avd etc. Edit question please, not just commetns :)

Comment: Why did you add the android-sdk-2.3 tag if the code targets Android 4 (If I understand 'Version 4.0.3' correctly)?  What version of Android does the phone support, what is it's make and model?

Answer (score 0):

You said you compiled it for 4.0.3. Try making an AVD with 2.3 (Gingerbread) and see if the apk installs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install it on your phone directly from Eclipse?

Enable USB Debugging, and plug your phone into your computer. When you run the app in eclipse it should install the app on your phone and then run it.

Answer (score -2):

Have you enabled "unknown sources"?

To enable or disable install of non-Market applications on your Android device:

1. Tap Home
2. Tap Menu
3. Tap Settings
4. Tap Applications
5. Tap Unknown sources checkbox to allow/disallow install of non-Market apps

[link](http://androidforums.com/tattoo-support-troubleshooting/13772-parse-error-there-problem-parsing-package.html#post3770996)

Comment: If one were to look in the original question, one would see that the OP did NOT originally say that they had enabled "unknown sources"

Comment: Not enabling unknown sources is unrelated to package parsing issues.